# Page refresh in Angular 2 with webpack results in index.html without styling/scripts

Tags: angular, webpack

I messed something up apparently because when I refresh the page or the HRM refreshes the page it goes to index.html (or '/') but I get the html code and the webpack head-config.common.js aren't injected. Also I saw that the webpack code (placeholder) is injected in the body instead of the head.

I'm using angular2-webpack, I compared the code/config/etc files with my project agains the angular2-webpack project I pulled from GitHub, and I don't see any differences except a few I made (including libraries in vendor.browser.ts).

I don't really know in what file I have to look, I just pasted my index.html file below. But please ask for specific code so I can paste it here too if you think the error might be in a different file.

This I what I get when I refresh the page:

[image]

Naturally it doesn't go to the right page because there aren't any scripts loaded...

This is what the page looks like:

[image]

This is my index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<title>
    <%= webpackConfig.metadata.title %>
</title>

 <meta name="description" content="<%= webpackConfig.metadata.title %>">

<% if (webpackConfig.htmlElements.headTags) { %>
        <%= webpackConfig.htmlElements.headTags %>
<% } %>

<base href="<%= webpackConfig.metadata.baseUrl %>">
</head>
<body>
  <fandango-app>
    <header class="collapsed">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <img src="/assets/img/logo-white-sm.png" />
            <div id="titles">
                <h1>fandango</h1>
                <h4>cloud, for the rest of us.</h4>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>
    <div id="loader" class="container text-center">
        <p>loading</p>
        <div class="loader">
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
        </div>
    </div>
   </fandango-app>

  <!-- Google Analytics: change UA-71073175-1 to be your site's ID -->
  <script>
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  ga('create', 'UA-71073175-1', 'auto');
  ga('send', 'pageview');
</script>

<% if (webpackConfig.metadata.isDevServer && webpackConfig.metadata.HMR !== true) { %>
    <!-- Webpack Dev Server reload -->
    <script src="/webpack-dev-server.js"></script>
<% } %>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, it's resolved, I never thought to `npm run clean` and `npm install`. This fixed it :-)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with the webpack starter I think you're using.
I used this as my starter [it's much simpler.](https://github.com/michaelbazos/angular2-starter)

It is a bit out of date, but my comparing it to the documentation for the webpack, I was able to update it.

I would post my updated version of it, but as I did it for a company project, I'm not sure if I would be allowed. But if you need help with the updating part, just let me know.

Ninja Edit: The one that most people use (by AngularClass) is very good, but it's very hard for a beginner Ng2 Dev to use. It's just a bit complicated for some things. (i.e. I don't need TDD)

Comment: I started from the AngularClass starter pack, and everything worked, it even worked when I configured it so it didn't use the hashtag. I don't know if this has to do with anything, but I started to get the problem after I cleaned the temp directory with ccleaner. Or it is just a total coïncidence... I don't really see anything in the code, even no differences in the modules when I compared the Angular Class webpack starter project with my project using winmerge.

Comment: I don't want to switch anymore as my application is starting to get big, it's just annoying that I can't refresh/enter the url. And soon I'm going to implement auth so I'll have to be able to enter an url to see if the login screen appears when browsing pages that require you to be logged in.

Comment: By the way, I'm hosting the build:prod on IIS10 with a redirect to index.html in the web.config, this just works as expected. Only when running npm run server (in Visual Studio Code) it doesn't work. I tried other projects and the all run correctly when refreshing/entering the url. It is specific to my app apparently...

Comment: Too noob-y at not-lurking to comment directly, but I'm glad you solved it.